# How do I get Ansible man pages to work on macOS? (installed with Homebrew)

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've installed Ansible on macOS 13.1 (Ventura) with Homebrew. After updating `$PATH` to include `/opt/homebrew/bin` so I can execute ansible commands. However, the `man` pages for Ansible (`man ansible`, `man ansible-galaxy`, etc.) do not work. The ansible `man` pages when installed with Homebrew are located at:

`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/7.1.0/share/man/man1`

How can I have the `man` command on macOS reference these pages?

Answer (score 2):

Even though I had `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` in `~/.zprofile` and `$MANPATH` was `/opt/homebrew/share/man::`, I'm assuming there was some symlinking problems as I noticed after `brew uninstall ansible` that ansible was still present in `/opt/homebrew/bin/` and the ansible command was still symlinked to it.

After doing `rm /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible*` and `brew install ansible`, ansible man pages are now working.

Answer (score 1):

The variable from which man works out where to look is MANPATH

From the bree manual page https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#shellenv and your comment on updating PATH I think you have not fully followed the install instructions

> Consider adding evaluation of this command’s output to your dotfiles (e.g. ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zprofile) with: eval "$(brew shellenv)"

Typing `brew shellenv` will show the updates needed for PATH MANPATH etc if you want to do it manually.

Comment: My `~/.zprofile` did contain `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` and `echo $MANPATH` is `/opt/homebrew/share/man::`.